# How can resolve recursion depth exceeded (Goose-extractor)

Tags: python, extractor, goose

I am one problem with goose-extractor
This is my code:

```
  for resultado in soup.find_all('a', href=True,text=re.compile(llave)):
        url = resultado['href']
        article = g.extract(url=url)
        print article.title
```

and take a look at my problem.

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

any suggestions ?

I am a lousy programmer or hidden errors are not visible in python

Comment: It doesn't fix whatever's wrong with the code, but you can set python's max recursion depth with `import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit()` - I think the default is 5000, and you can up it until you run out of memory or something else goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry, with your suggestions my Mac crash!

Comment: @papabombay is there no stack trace?

Comment: Yes but too extense !
anyway the author of goose - extractor who speaks French and my better tell me it's a problem of lxml library , but I still get consistent solution of the problem

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can increase the recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit()` ([2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit)/[3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit)):

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**5)
```

You can check what the default limit is with `sys.getrecursionlimit()` ([2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit)/[3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit)).

Of course, this won't fix whatever's causing this recursion (there's no way to know what's wrong without more details), and might crash your computer if you don't fix that.

Comment: Ok agree and that details need ?